# Основное и второстепенное значение букв

Tags: русская-графика

Наконец (ооовооо) выдался (оооовов) такой (овооо) вечер (ооово). Бабушка (оооооов) на (оо) несколько (оооово ов) дней (ооов) уехала (овооов) в (о) деревню (овоооов), а (о) папа (ооов) с (о) мамой (овово) ушли (оооо) в (о) театр (овооо). Светлана (оовоооов) осталась (воооово) дома (ооов) главной (ооооово) хозяйкой (ововвово). Вымыла (ововов) посуду (овоооо), подмела (овоовов) пол (ооо), полила (овооов) цветы (оовов) и (о) стала (оооов) с (о) братишкой (ооооооово) играть (ооооо).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наконец (ововооо).

на (ов) несколько (оооовоов) - предлог читается вместе с существительным, а передаёт редуцированный звук.

ехала (оовов) - буква е имеет два значения, но буква-то одна, а Вы посчитали за две.

деревню (овооооо), с (о) мамой (ооово) в (в) - перед глухим Т оглушается.

осталась (воооовоо) - Ь тоже буква, она обозначает мягкость согл., почему не засчитали?

вымыла (ооооов),  подмела (овоовоо) полила (овоооо) цветы (оовоо) и (о) стала (оооов)

с (в) - обозначает звук З братишкой (оовоооово) играть (оооооо) - не засчитали Ь.